# JS reference to the document by document.getElementById gives error back

Tags: javascript, less, getelementbyid, prefixfree

I have a webpage with [less](http://lesscss.org/) and [prefixfree](https://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/#) (both of them are js-files, imported from my own server) and now, when I've tried to import a custom script too, I got the problem:

Basic javascript like

```
x = "hello world";
alert (x);
```

works fine.

But every code which refers to my document like

```
alert (document.getElementById("content").innerHTML);
```

gives the console error

```
"document.getElementById("content").innerHTML is undefined"
```

Do you know what the problem could be? Any suggestions how to debug this are also welcome - I'm just despairing!

*edit*

the JS-files are all imported in the `<head>`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as \`getElementById\` not find the element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Comment: Are you sure to have an element with an id attribute **id="content"** dude ?

Comment: How and where in the page is the code being executed?

Comment: @user3241019 I'm sure. I've tried that also with different ids, with docuemnt.getElementByClassName or document.getElementByTagName. Always the same error message

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure your javascript is after your markup and make sure the element `id` is correct:

```
<div id="content">Beep boop</div>
<script>
    alert(document.getElementById("content").innerHTML);
</script>
```

Example: http://jsbin.com/sedagite/2/edit